# What is the difference between accessor and mutator methods?

Tags: c++

How are accessors and mutators different? An example and explanation would be great.

Comment: Accessor (or getter) methods allow you to access members of a data structure, while Mutator (or setter) methods allow you to change values of a data structure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An **accessor** is a class method used to *read* data members, while a **mutator** is a class method used to *change* data members.

Here's an example:

```
class MyBar;

class Foo
{
    public:
        MyBar GetMyBar() const { return mMyBar; } // accessor
        void SetMyBar(MyBar aMyBar) { mMyBar = aMyBar; } // mutator

    private:
        MyBar mMyBar;
}
```

It's best practice to make data members `private` (as in the example above) and only access them via accessors and mutators.  This is for the following reasons:

- You know when they are accessed (and can debug this via a breakpoint).
- The mutator can validate the input to ensure it fits within certain constraints.
- If you need to change the internal implementation, you can do so without breaking a lot of external code -- instead you just modify the way the accessors/mutators reference the internal data.

Answer (score 4):

```
class foo
{
    private:

        int a;
    public:
        int  accessA() const { return(a);}
        void mutateA(const int A) { a = A;}
}
```

Also known as getters and setters and probably a dozen other terms.

Comment: Your accessor should be const! :)

Comment: @Wesley Petrowski - fair enough but shouldn't everyone else's be too?

Comment: Yup, everyone elses should be too, but I didn't want to spam comments on every answer. +1 for you!

Comment: @Wesley - I made mine `const` too, just for completeness.

Comment: The question is about OO terminology; the only hint that OP cares about C++ is in the tag. Making functions `const` is just part of the C++ "anti-OO" B.S. that isn't really related to the concepts of accessor and mutator.  The fact that the accessor doesn't change the state is enough to make it an accessor. `const` just means we can invoke the accessor on `const` qualified object or similarly qualified references thereto. `const` allows for different overloads to coexist, but that's specifically when mutation is going on: the overloaded function isn't an abstract accessor.