# How to push_back to a list with getter function?

Tags: c++, list, oop, getter-setter

I have getter setter function like this.

```
void Student::setStudentName(std::__cxx11::string b)
{
    cout<<"Enter the student name"<<endl;
    cin >> studentName;
    int size = b.size();
    if(size > 0 && size<20)
        studentName = b;
    else
        cout<<"Please enter a name between 1-20 char"<<endl;
}
string Student::getStudentName() const
{
    return studentName;
}
```

What i want to do is add to the list with getter function.

```
void Student::addStudent()
{
    int studentAdd;
    cout<<"How many student do you want to add?"<<endl;
    cin>>studentAdd;

    for(int i=0;i<studentAdd;++i)
    {
        setStudentName("a");
        getStudentList().push_back(getStudentName());
    }
}
```

I tried like this but

```
getStudentList().push_back(getStudentName());
```

this code didn't work. What could be the problem?

And here is the list's getter/setter

```
void Student::setStudentList(list<string> a)
{
    studentList = a;
}
list<string> Student::getStudentList() const
{
    return studentList;
}
```

Comment: Show `getStudentList()`. You are probably returning a copy.

Comment: sorry i add the getStudentList function.

Comment: Return a reference instead of a copy: `list<string>& Student::getStudentList()`.

Comment: i did your format but i get another error.

Comment: list<string>& Student::getStudentList() const
{
    return studentList; // compiler didnt let me compile here 
}

Comment: Remove `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the return type of `getStudentList`. As it stands you're returning a copy of it, and then appending to the temporary copy, which then immediately gets destroyed.

What you want is to return a reference to the *actual* list.

```
list<string> &Student::getStudentList() {
    return studentList;
}
```

You then shouldn't make such a function `const` because it is (potentially) a [mutator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627093/what-is-the-difference-between-accessor-and-mutator-methods).

---

The matter of `const` is sometimes handled by having two overrides of `getStudentList`. One which is `const` both in return type and [cv-qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv), and one which isn't const in either.

```
// accessor override
const list<string> &Student::getStudentList() const { 
    return studentList;
}

// mutator override
list<string> &Student::getStudentList() { 
    return studentList;
}
```

This enables the appropriate override to be deduced in the different calling scenarios.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) And i changed the setter function a little bit and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

as the answers above, you need to return a reference so you can update it by **push_back**, and this also explains why you need to remove **const**.

```
list<string> &Student::getStudentList() {
     return studentList;
}
```

note :: be aware of returning a reference to a local/not independent variable.

please take a look on [Is the practice of returning a C++ reference variable evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752658/is-the-practice-of-returning-a-c-reference-variable-evil).